# Cache file in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have to download a jar file (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mock-server/mockserver-netty/5.13.2/mockserver-netty-5.13.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar).

Maven central does not contain this `with-dependencies` and I cannot just specify it in a dependency list (`implementation("group:artifact:version-with-dependencies)`).

I can download it (by creating a custom task) to the `build` directory, but I also would like to cache it like other dependencies (to avoid downloading it each time after cleaning the `build` folder).

So, it would be nice either to specify this long url and Gradle would download/cache it automatically, or to use some API to cache it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [comment](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/issues/89#issuecomment-357546805) solution in Kotlin:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("de.undercouch.download") version "5.1.0"
}

val url = "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mock-server/mockserver-netty/5.13.2/mockserver-netty-5.13.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar"

task("downloadMockServerToCache", Download::class) {
    val destPath = urlToCachePath(url)
    src(url)
    dest(destPath)
    overwrite(false)
}

task("copyMockServerFromCache", Copy::class) {
    dependsOn("downloadMockServerToCache")
    val destPath = urlToCachePath(url)
    from(destPath) {
        include(urlToCachedFile(url))
    }
    into("build/bin")
    rename { "$mockServerArtifact.jar" }
}

fun urlToCachePath(url: String): String {
    val urlWithoutProtocol = url.substringAfter("//")
    val reversedDomain = reversedDomain(urlWithoutProtocol)
    val fileName = urlToCachedFile(url)
    val gradleHome = System.getProperty("user.home")
    return "$gradleHome/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/de.undercouch/cache/$reversedDomain/$fileName"
}

fun urlToCachedFile(url: String): String {
    return url.substringAfterLast("/").substringBefore("?")
}

fun reversedDomain(urlWithoutProtocol: String) =
    urlWithoutProtocol.substringBefore("/").split(".").reversed().joinToString("/")
```